# Add number steps on top of bootstrap progress bar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

How can I add steps (circles with numbers inside) on top of Bootstrap 4 progress bar in a way that they are equally divided. I was of thinking in something like this:

```css
// css
.wrapper-progress-step {
  /* what should go here? this would guarantee that steps are 'floating' on top of the bar*/
}

.steps {
  /*what should go here? probably position relative to go on top of the bar*/
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-progress-step">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- this should go above the progress bar dividing the bar in equally spaces -->
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you guys think this way is viable? Open to new ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
.steps {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Flexbox provides an easy way to devide equally. This will give you a nudge in the right direction i think.